# Getstream Support with Lumen

Tags: getstream-io

I'm trying to use getstream with Lumen and it seems like the laravel package they created is not compatible with Lumen. Is there anyone out here used getstream with Lumen?

Comment: Now, GetStream v>=2.3.0 has supported.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your GitHub issue about this as well. I'll be looking into our PHP support very soon, and have spoken to my colleagues here at Stream about ORM-level support. Since our Laravel client library hooks into Eloquent, it should be easy enough to reduce it to simple Eloquent support at the ORM level, allowing folks to use it in any framework or application using that ORM.

Comment: Looking forward for it.